# Video Editing and Storing in AWS Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, fileserver, amazon-workspaces

Currently we have numerous video assets in **S3** that our Video team needs to edit daily/hourly. Each day they spend hours downloading these assets, editing them, and re uploading them. **Is there a way for us to keep these assets in the cloud and allow editing on the AWS cloud?**

I was thinking of having a file server built then spinning up Windows machines in **EC2** that could connect to the **file server**.Is there better option available for this scenario ??

Comment: What do you mean by "video editing"? Are they simply splicing together parts of existing videos, or are they doing creative activities such as adding effects and voiceovers? What type of Internet connection do you have been these users and AWS -- are they all in the same office, or are they working remotely?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [getting started with AWS cloud video editing](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/getting-started-with-aws-cloud-video-editing/) article on AWS. It explains in some detail what you may be trying to achieve.

[image]

**There is also this** [AWS quick starts page](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/?solutions-all.sort-by=item.additionalFields.sortDate&solutions-all.sort-order=desc&awsf.filter-content-type=*all&awsf.filter-tech-category=*all&awsf.filter-industry=*all&solutions-all.q=video%2Bediting&solutions-all.q_operator=AND) that could save you alot of time when it comes to deploying different common solutions. This link will take you to some "video editing" search results.

[image]

Comment: Can we achieve the same with AWS workspace ?is that would be cost effective for our users ??

Comment: I Don't have experience with workspace, but there are also other third party solutions like this -> https://blog.ipv.com/remote-cloud-video-editing-with-amazon-aws-just-got-a-lot-cheaper  that claim to offer huge savings, that you can look at. PS: i have no affiliation with this company

Comment: Thank nick ,are  you used there services ever  ?? are there any easy strait forward solution available to my scenario ?

Comment: I can't recommend one or the other, but id say take a look at the AWS solutions first. It all depends on your budget and preference in the end. Please mark my answer above if it helped you. thanks